# How to assign credentials of current (Windows) user to ftpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, iis

How do I assign the current (windows) credentials to ftpWebRequest.
I do not want to specify credentials explicitly , rather use the user's (loggedin) current windows credentials
 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your web.config, you need the following:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

And then in IIS, you configure your app pool to run in integrated mode.

Then in your code that calls the ftpwebrequest, you can use the security pricipal - e.g:

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```